# Which algorithum is used in traversing UIViewRoot in JSF?

Tags: jsf, viewroot

In JSF a UIViewRoot is created for our JSF page. When we traverse it, which algorithum is used to traverse it?

Comment: You can find that in the JSF specification document

Comment: I tried to find that , but did not find. If you have any reference please share it with me.

Comment: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html

Comment: Thanks Kolossus, but what you have given is Portlet specification, it doesn't contains JSF specification.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at, but I just downloaded the files from that very link and the PDF in the zip files has "JSF 2.0 specification" in bold on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if "algorithm" is the right wording. It at least supports both [iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) and [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) patterns.

Iterator goes via [`UIComponent#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent-java.lang.String-) (click link to see extensive javadoc describing the search algorithm).

```
UIComponent found = someComponent.findComponent(clientIdExpression);
// ...
```

Visitor goes via [`UIComponent#visitTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree-javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext-javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback-) and [`UIComponent#invokeOnComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#invokeOnComponent-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-javax.faces.component.ContextCallback-).

```
someComponent.visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), Arrays.asList(clientId), null), new VisitCallback() {
    @Override
    public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent found) {
        // ...    
        return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
    }
});
```

```
someComponent.invokeOnComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), clientId, new ContextCallback() {
    @Override
    public void invokeContextCallback(FacesContext context, UIComponent found) {
        // ...    
    }
});
```

Either way, `someComponent` can represent the `UIViewRoot` itself, but it can basically be any parent component you want.